# addEventListener not working when menu buttons removed *Fixed*

Tags: actionscript-3, event-listener, removechild

In my main I have a menu of buttons, and a map added which is a class of it's own, I wanted it so that when I click on a "view map" button, it would remove the buttons so the map could be viewed, problem is when the specific button is removed it seems to stop the event listener working.

Here's the code, I've tried to chop it down as much as I can just to show you the part that's the problem.

```
    public function Main () {
    drawButtons(); // draws all the buttons and adds them to the buttonList array
    // the buttons are all made from a "ButtonClass".
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
}

public function onMouseUp(Event:MouseEvent):void {
    else if (Event.target.name == "viewMapB") {

        // imagine removeChild(buttonList[1-8]) commands here.
        removeChild(buttonList[9]); // when this is removed, eventlistener wont work

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyPressedUp);
        stage.focus = stage; // This line fixed the problem
    }
}

private function keyPressedUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    trace("ping");

    // goneBack("main"); // brings back the menu that was removed
}
```

experimenting seems to show that it's only when I remove buttonList[9] that this problem arises, but all the work arounds I could think of so far refuse to work.

Edit 1: to show where the mouseEvent comes from.

Edit 2: Attempted adding stage.addeventlistenever to main as well. No luck, but found that after clicking on the button, if I click again afterwards (the map covers the whole stage area), the eventlistener works again. Now trying to figure out why that is...

Edit 3: Seemed the problem had something to do with focus. Adding "stage.focus = stage;" in after the KEY_UP event listener seems to have fixed it. Learn something everyday! Also thank you to those who helped solve this weird problem.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but couldn't you just hide or disable the buttons instead of removing them?

Comment: You chopped it down too much... we cannot see anything from your code. Not even to what object is the onMouseUp assigned.

Comment: @Fygo is correct, we're assuming your `MouseEvent` is tied to your button.

Comment: I've changed it to show where the mouseEvent is coming from, I didn't tie it to anything but if it helps I spose I can tie it to stage. Originally the buttons are draw in the "drawButtons()" function, which adds a bunch of "button classes" I made up into an array which is the buttonList.

Comment: try stage.addEventListener() in your main() instead

Comment: if there are only comments, you cannot mark an answer. i don't really know why this would solve your error, so don't worry about it. in general you should add stuff to the stage like you did with the KeyboardEvent if you're going with this approach.

Comment: OH, one thing I noticed,,, after clicking the button, if I click again (anyway the map covers the whole stage area) it makes the eventlistener to work... Which seems odd. Now I think I recalled seeing another problem that sounded similar to this earlier...